# Unable to execute query - Error: Incorrect syntax near 'Media'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, nvarchar

This code is showing an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Media'.

What does it mean? Where am I making a mistake?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["sub"] != null)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "select * from entry_table Where sub=" + Request.QueryString["sub"],
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cozmotestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["sub"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["body"].ToString();
        }
    }
}

<div style=" padding-bottom:10px"><h1><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h1></div>

<div><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `Request.QueryString["sub"]` exactly? What is the type of `sub` column?

Comment: `"select * from entry_table Where sub="` <-- I think you miss ' around the string that sub equals (which i think would be a string with the value 'Media').

Comment: Please, please, please learn about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I think in the Request.QueryString["sub"] have string “Media” so it is clear you have syntax problem to execute sql query so change like "select * from entry_table Where sub='" + Request.QueryString["sub"] + "'".

Comment: subject column is type of nvarchar.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged [nvarchar](/questions/tagged/nvarchar) with your question, I assume your `sub` column is `nvarchar`.

That's why you need to use single quotes with it's values. Like;

```
..sub = '" + Request.QueryString["sub"] + "'"..
```

### But don't use this way.

Much more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` as well.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cozmotestConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from entry_table Where sub = @sub";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Request.QueryString["sub"];
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con))
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);

         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["sub"].ToString();
             Label2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["body"].ToString();
         }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need single quotes around your value in your where clause.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from entry_table Where sub='" + Request.QueryString["sub"] + "'", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cozmotestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Although, I would highly recommend that you use a parametrized query to avoid SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, it may help you on this issue,

```
string str = Request.QueryString["sub"];
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cozmotestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "select * from entry_table Where sub='"+str+"'",con)
//Your remaining parts will come here
```

Please let me know the result.